# SPARQL (newbie) - optionally set a variable depending on it's type

Tags: sparql

I'm beginning to learn SPARQL and I'm struggling with extracting the right value for a country, given a place that may be a country, a town, a state or some other place (e.g. a factory).

I'm using dbpedia, specifically information about Automobiles. Below is a query that demonstrates the core of my issue:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT
    ?car, ?country, ?assembly
WHERE {
    ?car  a                  dbpedia-owl:Automobile .

    FILTER regex(?car,'19[34][0-9]_Ford') . # Keep the example small

    ?car  dbpedia-owl:assembly   ?assembly .

    OPTIONAL { ?assembly dbpedia-owl:country ?country } . # city
    OPTIONAL { ?assembly dbpedia-owl:state/dbpedia-owl:country ?country } . # State
}

ORDER BY ?car, ?assembly
```

This returns a list of ford cars made in the 1930's and 40's, with the places they were assembled at, and (my attempt at resolving) the country they were made in.

The challenge is that the assembly predicate can resolve to a city, a state, a country, a factory or some other place.

For example, the Ford_1941 has both http://dbpedia.org/resource/Australia and http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chester_Assembly.

The two OPTIONAL clauses I've added cater for city and state, but I'd like to populate ?country in the other cases i.e. when ?assembly is actually a country, set ?country to ?assembly, and find the country for a factory.

(I suspect for factory to country, I'm just going to have to work out the graph and specify it in an OPTIONAL clause, unless someone can enlighten me otherwise)

Many thanks in advance

Pip

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to populate the variable `?country` to the country` if the assembly is a country and if the assembly is a factory to the country the factory is located in?

Comment: Hi AKSW - first of all sorry for my tardy and slow response. You are correct. I want to populate country to the country if it's a country, city, town, state or factory (I suspect I won't be able to get a country for a factory in many cases)